# set permissions in aiogram

Tags: python, telegram-bot, aiogram

I would like to manage/set the group permissions in `aiogram` using a bot.

Relevant Link:
https://docs.aiogram.dev/en/latest/telegram/types/chat.html?highlight=edit%20permissions#aiogram.types.chat.Chat.set_permissions

Answer (score 0):

I can't test it but based on `telegram-bot` `issues` [Append/Update on ChatPermissions](https://github.com/python-telegram-bot/python-telegram-bot/issues/1834)  it can be

```
# set `True` or `False`
permissions = {
    'can_send_messages': None, 
    'can_send_media_messages': None, 
    'can_send_polls': None, 
    'can_send_other_messages': None, 
    'can_add_web_page_previews': None, 
    'can_change_info': None, 
    'can_invite_users': None, 
    'can_pin_messages': None
}

#permissions.update(current)
#permissions.update(new)

new_permissions = ChatPermissions(**permissions)

context.bot.set_chat_permissions(chat_id=chat_id, permissions=new_permissions)
```